# How to check if the date already passed the date from the list ? in java

Tags: java, date

alright, so what I have is a ScheduledExxecutorService which checks every second if the date from the list of dates has passed, code:

```
public void dateCheckinator(){
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                for(int i=0;i<dateList.size();i++){
                    if (cal.getTime()>dateList.get(i)){
                        kaladeList.add(kaladeList.get(i));
                    kaladeListats.add(kaladeListats.get(i));
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(cal.getTime());
            }
        };
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

However I get error at if statement, how do I check if the date has passed ? I will change scheduler to checking every minute or so instead of seconds later on.

Comment: FYI: this code seems really flawed `kaladeList.add(kaladeList.get(i));`. Why would you add an element to `kaladeList` that you are getting from `kaladeList`? Shouldn't this be `kaladeList.add(dateList.get(i));`

Comment: I appreciate the concern, but that's exactly what I want to do, copy the earlier members of the list to the end of the list. I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing that but I'm still learning and just experimenting with this whole program.

Comment: dateList type is Date and I got an unspecified error. works fine now with the suggestion posted below !

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).  `Instant.now().isAfter( myDate.toInstant() )`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java you are supposed to use `after` or `before` Methods.

```
if (cal.getTime().after(dateList.get(i))){
   kaladeList.add(kaladeList.get(i));
   kaladeListats.add(kaladeListats.get(i));
}
```

Comment: The `>` operator is looking at the memory location of the two `Date` objects, not invoking `Date`-specific comparison logic as `after` does.

Comment: +1 good answer, next time consider giving the why as well as the what. It will help the OP to understand the nature of the error.

Comment: You are right, thank you for your complementing my answer.

Comment: thanks,this seems to do the job.